# How to instantiate a view which is created in storyboard in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to create a UITableView with custom table headers. The problem is I am fairly new to Swift and can't quite understand how to create layouts programmatically. So I decided to create my view in storyboard, then instantiate in Swift. My questions:

1. I only need a button near the default table view header. Is implementing a custom header best way to achieve this? (I also need to change colors of header)
2. Lets say it is best to create a custom view for headers. Should I create a label and a button then add constraints programmatically. If so, how? Or should I create a view in storyboard and instantiate it in Swift instead.
3. If it is better to create it in storyboard. How to do it?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to create table header view or what?